# Centering text vertically and horizontally in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and I am attempting to make a Cell that is 100% height and width of its host container.

The title is 30% of that space and the value is 70%. There are upper and lower limits of the value that take up 20% each leaving 60% of the space for the actual value.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid parameterContainer">
<div class="row paramHead">
    <span class="virtAlignFix"></span>
    <div class="centerText">
      SPO2 (%)
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row paramValWrapper">
  <div class="row paramLimit">
    <span class="virtAlignFix"></span>
    <div class="centerText">
    200
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row paramValue">
    <span class="virtAlignFix"></span>
    <div class="centerText">
    80
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row paramLimit">
    <span class="virtAlignFix"></span>
     <div class="centerText">
     40
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.virtAlignFix {
    line-height: 100%;
}

.parameterContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.paramValWrapper {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}

.paramLimit {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
}

.paramHead {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
}

.paramValue {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center
}

.centerText {
 vertical-align:middle; 
    display:inline-block;  
}
```

Fiddle of my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/WCBjN/1173/

EDIT: added height % to body and page.

Comment: CSS 101: heights in percentages only work if the parent element has an explicit height set as well.

Comment: yes, that is the case

Comment: No, it is not. The parent of `.parameterContainer` does not have any height set.

Comment: oic in my fiddle. Ok I updated it. As you see the values are at to top of the Div.

Comment: `line-height: 100%` also does not do what you appear to think it does. You really need to do a little more research. Centering stuff has been discussed to death a million times over already.

Comment: see also:  https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making text central is fairly trivial, the easiest approach is as follows. You can check out the jsFiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/jL9bs0j7/

```css
.text-container {
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-container span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
  <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry kinda new to css.

Comment: No worries, this little trick is nice and simple and saves lots of complicated work-arounds.